# Subclass and class methods

Tags: objective-c, subclass, uibezierpath

I would like to subclass UIBezierPath to add a CGPoint property.

```
@interface MyUIBezierPath : UIBezierPath
@property  CGPoint origin;
@end
```

I'm using it like this:

```
MyUIBezierPath * path0 = [MyUIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 190) byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners 
    cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
```

The compiler complains with: `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'MyUIBezierPath *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIBezierPath *'`

`bezierPathWithRoundedRect` returns an UIBezierPath.

So I cannot send `setOrigin:` to path0, not being an instance of MyUIBezierPath.

What should I modify to have `bezierPathWithRoundedRect` return an instance of my class ?

Edit: After reading a related question, I feel like subclassing may not be the best thing to do in this case (extending UIBezierPath functionalities).

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is by overriding the method in the subclass and changing the class of the returned object:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect)rect cornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [super bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:cornerRadius];

    object_setClass(path, self);

    return path;
}
```

The cleaner way to do this is to use Associated Objects to add the property to `UIBezierPath` in a category.

e.g.:

```
static const char key;
- (CGPoint)origin
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key) CGPointValue];
}

- (void)setOrigin:(CGPoint)origin
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:origin], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, bezierPathWithRoundedRect returns a UIBezierPath 'cause it is a method of the class UIBezierPath. You have to create a method in your new subclass (MyUIBezierPath) equivalent to the one of the parent class that obviously creates a instance of that parent class.

But I think it is very hard to do as there are no methods to invoke. FWIK it's almost impossible to do without a method like "initWithRoundedRect:byRoundingCorners:cornerRadii:"

Comment: So your're saying that I have to create `initWithRoundedRect` that is a reimplementation of `bezierPathWithRoundedRect`. I don't really see code reuse here. Shouldn't I try to do something with the UIBezierPath instance returned by `bezierPathWithRoundedRect` ?

Comment: The problem is that it will always return a UIBezierPath instance. As far as the only way to create and initialize instances is using class methods, I cannot figure how to initialize a subclass of that class.